# Get Value of an List<Object[]>

Tags: java

I have a problem that I think simple but I can't resolve it :D

I have a List and I want to get for exemple the second value of the second Object of this List. But, How can I do that ??

This is an example of the List display into the browser :

```
[[248,6,"Expired"],[123,2,"In Progress"]]
```

And my code :

```
List<Object[]> myList = ......; // myList contains the two objects display above.
```

For example, I want to get ( for do tests on this ) the second value of the second object in my example, so in this example : '2';

Thanks for your help

Comment: Something like `myList.get(1)[1]` .

Comment: read about [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int))

Comment: Thanks Arnaud, like I said, it was easy xD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get specific ArrayList item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920602/get-specific-arraylist-item)

Comment: int num = (int)myList.get(1)[1];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get datas from List<Object> (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123299/how-to-get-datas-from-listobject-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myList.get(1)[1]
```

`myList.get(1)` give you the second array in the list and `[1]` give you the second object in that array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below format:

```
(myList.get(<index of object>))[<index of element in object array>]
```

In your case, both of these indices will be 1.

```
(myList.get(1))[1]
```

Comment: This answer is not adding any extra information as already given with the answer of Ricola

Comment: That is true. We seem to answered it same time approximately. At the time I started answering this, the mentioned answer was not there.